# Angular ng-repeat: construct new object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

var `$scope.notif` holds this data:

[image]

In a popup, I want to view the different messages, so I used:

```
<ion-list><ion-item ng-repeat="n in notif">{{n.msg}}</ion-item></ion-list>
```

While message 1 and message 2 are there, there are also 3 empty list items, probably because the length of the data is 5 because of the `msg`, `msg_title`and `notif_type`.

**Example** showing the empty list items [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VebGMG).

Can I somehow tell Angular repeat the length minus 3?

I've tried removing the 3 extra items in the object using:

```
    for(var i=0; i<($scope.notif.length); i++) {
            $scope.notifnew.push($scope.notif[i]);
    }
```

But `$scope.notifnew` is now `undefined`...

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: `$scope.notif` is an object not an array.

Comment: @Sajeetharan I've added a codepen example

Comment: you do not want to show those 3 items?

Comment: No, just "Message 1" and "Message 2" (or more if there are more), but never the empty lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out properties that you don't like:

```
var data = test.notification.android.payload;
$scope.notif = Object.keys(data).filter(function(key){
  return /^\d+$/.test(key); // or !!data[key].msg
}).map(function(key){
  return  data[key];
});
```

I've [updated your plunker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZmyqq?editors=101).

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.notif.length` won't work because `$scope.notif` is an object not an array. You can iterate with:

```
var messages = []; 
angular.forEach($scope.notif, function(val, key){

    if (!isNaN(parseInt(key))) {
        messages.push(val);
    } 
})
```

But this structure seems "broken" to me. Furthermore payload should be an array imo.

```
var test = {
    "user_ids":["...","..."],
    "notification":
    {
        "alert":"dummy",
        "android":{
            "title":"New alert 2",
            "payload":{
                "msg":"lala",
                "msg_title":"Thanks!",
                "notif_type":"alert",
                "0":{
                    "msg":"Message 1"
                },
                "1":{
                    "msg":"Message 2","msg_title":"Thanks!"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```